# float to short conversion error in c

Tags: pic, c

I implemented dc motor speed control project but there is one problem which i am not able to figure out .The problem is that my pid output which is float when assigned to short data type gives unexpected answer.since PWM inbuilt function in mikroc allows only short type dutycycle there is a need of float to short conversion.
please help
i am using pic16F877A.

```
    example 
    float to short conversion:
    float pid_out;
    short duty=(short)pid_out;
    outputs:
    if my pid_out<=100
    then duty=pid_out;
    and if my pid_out>100
    duty=65535
```

for pid_out values less than or equal to hundred it gives same value for duty
 whereas for pid_out values greater than 100 it gives  duty value in the range of 65500.
please help unable to understand what is the mistake.
 For reading the values i used virtual terminal and uart.

Comment: Use "unsigned short" (in both places you use short)

Comment: where should i use unsigned short. I mean LHS or RHS

Comment: unsigned short duty=(unsigned short)pid_out;

Comment: it is working can u explain me the logic please

Comment: short is 8-bit signed so the range is -128 to 127. 255 is thus cast as -1. Somewhere along the way after what you have written, -1 is cast to unsigned int, which yields 65535.

Comment: Your code also does not match the subsequent description. To make equivalent the two "if" statements need to read like: "if(pid_out <= 100)" and "if(pid_out > 100)".

Comment: Note that the **cast** `(short)` or `(unsigned short)` is not needed. The compiler will do the **conversion** without you telling it to.

Comment: You likely do not need floating point arithmetics for this program. Neither PID regulation nor PWM calls for float. If you actually do need floats, you shouldn't be using the least code effective MCU on the market.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should know that casting float to int or short, can result in *undefined behavior*, if the float has a value outside the range of the integer. So, if that is possible, you should think about how to handle the exception cases, if pid_out>255, or pid_out<0.

Otherwise the answer to your question is to use a "unsigned short" data type:

```
unsigned short duty=(unsigned short)pid_out;
```

This casts pid_out in the range 0..255, the same range as duty can hold.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types for a list of C data types.

Comment: If MISRA-C and a static analyser would be used, then well-known compile-time bugs like this one would have been immediately spotted.